# Change background with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm using this JQuery code to change the background after five seconds, how can I make the backgrounds fade/animate instead of just instantly changing?

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
    var body = $('header');
    var backgrounds = [
      'url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/header-boy.jpg)',
      'url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/header-boy-hover.jpg)'];
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        body.css(
            'background',
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Use `.animate()` instead of `.css`.

Comment: Could you give more details on how to do this?

Comment: @BradHouston - there is much documentation on the [`animate()` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), why not attempt to implement it and then return if you face any more issues.

Comment: I'm trying and I'm failing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CSS transitions which are quite simple to use:

```
body {
   background-color: white;
   transition: background-color 1s 5s ease;
}

body.new-background-color {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Now in your JavaScript, just use Add class on the body element to add class:

```
jQuery('body').addClass('new-background-color');
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work with no problems as long as you don't need it to work with the older devil browser (IE8 or below).

Comment: also, I made the transition on background-color for simplicity, you could just as easily do it on background and then change the image with the new class to get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this this, this may help
[codepen link is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyVQGJ)

```
var interval = setInterval(changePic,10);
var currentColor = [0,0,0];
function changePic(){
  $('#head').css({background: 'rgb(' + currentColor[0] + ',' + currentColor[1] + ',' + currentColor[2] + ')'});
  currentColor[0] = increaseColor(currentColor[0]);
  //currentColor[1] = increaseColor(currentColor[1]);
  currentColor[2] = increaseColor(currentColor[2]);

}
function increaseColor(colValue){
  colValue = (colValue > 255)? 0 : (colValue + 1);
  return colValue;
}
```